# prometheus skip certificate verification

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I deployed Prometheus with the [helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus) to my Kubernetes cluster. When checking the targets, I see that my cockroachdb is down because of a certificate error:

```
Get "https://10.244.0.48:8080/_status/vars": x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, not 10.244.0.48
```

The Cockroachdb service has these annotations:

```
prometheus.io/path: _status/vars
    prometheus.io/port: '8080'
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
```

How can I set `insecure_skip_verify` for Cockroachdb?

Comment: If you'll read [tag:kubernetes] tag description, you'll see this quote: "KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here."

Comment: You might want to try: tls_config:
                                         insecure_skip_verify: true